# $2k^2+7k=2mk+3m+36$. Find all non-negative integer solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried this:

$2k(k-m)+7k-3m-36=0$. And I'm stuck. How do I solve this one?

Comment: What are $k,m$?

Comment: i've forgot that they have to be integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is your turn to see if you understand the method for finding a product which helps. Write your equation as $$2k^2-2mk+7k-3m-36=0$$

Factorise the highest degree terms as $2k^2-2mk=2m(k-m)$

To obtain an expression which picks up the lower terms leaving only a constant you need $$(2m+a)(k-m+b)=2k^2-2mk+7k-3m+C$$ where you are not concerned with what $C$ is until the end. This works because the higher order terms have already been taken care of and you fix $a$ and $b$ from the linear terms.

The plug the factorisation into the original expression.

You should get an expression equivalent to Dr Graubner's solution.

If you think about it you might be able to see that you are finding integer points on a hyperbola.

Comment: yeah i got a=3 b=2 c=42 and it came out

Answer (score 2):

solving for $m$ we get $m=k+2-\frac{42}{2k+3}$

Comment: thanks. now just 2k+3 divides 42 and y is determined for each x.